# System.OutOfMemoryException: Out Of Memory

Tags: c#, graphics

I'm making a game which uses Graphics to draw random pictures from the folder.
[Here It Is:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/czKpH.png)

This is for a game on C#

```
public static int cookiecount;
public static Random random = new Random();
public static string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(Application.StartupPath, "*.png");
public static Image im;

public static void Draw(System.Drawing.Graphics g, int x, int y)
{
    try
    {
        im = Image.FromFile(files[random.Next(0, files.Count())]);

        g.DrawImage(im, x, y, 40, 40);
    }
    catch(Exception ee) {
        MessageBox.Show("Error! " +ee.Message + " " + ee.Source + " " + ee.HelpLink,
            "Oh No", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }

    cookiecount++;
}
```

It outputs an error that says:

> System.OutOfMemoryException: Out Of Memory

Comment: The image is not disposed, meaning there is a memory leak. After a certain time you will run out of memory. In addition, for performance reasons, it may be better to cache each type of image once in memory (e.g. the cookie image, the candy image etc.) instead of loading them from the disk in each draw.

Comment: look up `IDisposable` and how to use `using(...) { ...}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have said, you have a memory leak as you are not disposing the images. Note: usually memory of unused objects gets freed up automatically in C#, but images are special, as they are COM-objects, i.e. non-.NET-objects.

Instead of loading the images over and over, load them once. Since the same images are used during the whole game, you don't need to dispose them.

```
public static int cookiecount;
public static Random random = new Random();
public static Image[] images;

// Call this once at program start.
public static LoadImages()
{
    string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(Application.StartupPath, "*.png");
    images = new Image[files.Length];
    for (int i = 0; i < files.Length; i++) {
        images[i] = Image.FromFile(files[i]);
    }
}

public static void Draw(System.Drawing.Graphics g, int x, int y)
{
    int index = random.Next(0, images.Length);
    g.DrawImage(images[index], x, y, 40, 40);

    cookiecount++;
}
```

For arrays, use the `Length` property instead of calling the `Count()` extension method. It is more efficient.

Also, the exception handling should be moved to `LoadImages()`. For sake of simplicity, I did not show it here.

Comment: Still... Here: ```images[i] = Image.FromFile(files[i]);```

Comment: `Image.FromFile` is still here, but it is called only once per image instead of in the `Draw` method that is called many times for each image.

Comment: Make sure that you are calling `LoadImages()` only once. Don't call it in a loop!  Loading images can throw this exception if the format of the image is not recognized.

Comment: Thank You! I'll be testing it!